# How can I create a scrolling display in python

Tags: python

I would like to use python to create an application which displays the output of an electrocardiograph (essentially a voltage against time graph).

I intend to do this by having a fixed window that is, for example 200 pixels wide. I would then update the 200th column every X seconds and slide all of the previous pixels 1 pixel to the left, creating a scrolling display.

How can this be achieved using python?